# How to fix remote gpg agent when it stops working?

Tags: linux, gpg, gpg-agent, yubikey

This is driving me crazy.  I previously asked this:
[gpg-agent mysteriously stopped working - agent on remote system no longer connecting to ssh socket](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415110/gpg-agent-mysteriously-stopped-working-agent-on-remote-system-no-longer-connec)

If I log out overnight everything will work when I connect the next day.  I have tried killing all agent processes on both local and remote, removing all sockets to no avail.

I think the trigger for the problem is running RSYNC or SCP from another terminal on the local computer.

Does anyone know the steps to troubleshoot and/or fix this?

Comment: I finally figured this out.  See comment added to other question at the top

Comment: The other question of yours has been reopened. Should this be considered a duplicate of that one?

Comment: yes, I asked this again in hopes that someone knew

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gpg-agent mysteriously stopped working - agent on remote system no longer connecting to ssh socket](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415110/gpg-agent-mysteriously-stopped-working-agent-on-remote-system-no-longer-connec)

Comment: yes, I posted the solution in gpg-agent mysteriously stopped working - agent on remote system no longer connecting to ssh socket.  Please mark this as a duplicate.